# How can you display a trailing dot in an \SI?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

The LaTeX package `siunitx` provides an `\SI` command for displaying values with SI units. For example, writing `\SI{100}{\milli\gram}` displays `100 mg` with proper typesetting.

When expressing this value with explicitly 3 significant figures, you can either use scientific notation "1.00 × 10<sup>2</sup> mg" or the more convenient "100. mg" (notice the trailing dot). In some situations, I would prefer the trailing dot notation.

If you write `\SI{100.}{\milli\gram}` in LaTeX, it implicitly adds a zero after the decimal point: `100.0 mg`. This is incorrect, as it specifies 4 significant figures, rather than 3.

Is there a way to prevent the command from implicitly adding a zero after the decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\SI[add-decimal-zero=false]{123.}{kg}
```

If you want it permanently:

```
\sisetup{add-decimal-zero=false}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!